# What does "perfect" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Man sits and holds a baby, and says:

> Look at you, so big, so ***perfect***. I can't imagine a joy of spending every day with her...

So, I'm trying to understand what it precisely means when you say that the baby is perfect. Please, enlighten me.

I'd really appreciate any help on this one. :)

Comment: The second sentence puzzles me. Either a word like “greater” is missing before _joy_ (and the sentence continues wit “than”), or this man can really not see how spending time with this kid is going to bring him any joy. Which is possible, but contradicts the first sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfect in this context means "without imperfections" (defects). A baby is new; no signs of aging, no scars; no wear and tear. It is soft and smooth, petite and innocent - idealized. If it were a car, we might say, "fresh off the assembly line" (no scratches, no dust, no oil stains, no signs of use, etc.) Babies are never perfect in the same sense as we say an adult is perfect (should we ever say that).

Answer (score 0):

When a parent says that to a baby-child, it means **"I'm madly in love with you"**.  It doesn't have the literal meaning of perfection or flawlessness as most loving fathers and mothers will always find their healthy babies perfect.